# How to load a UITableView from a nib file into a container view in a parent view controller?

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib, nib, uicontainerview

I am trying to load a view controller (lets call this VC2) that contains a table view into a container view within a parent view controller (VC1). The issue I am running into is when I try register the nib or set delegate/data source of the tableview in VC2 I am getting a nil error.

I have tried removing the `delegate` and `dataSource` connection but this just loads a blank tableview

This is the code I used to transfer data to the container view controller:

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let listVC = segue.destination as? BusinessListViewController {
            listVC.bottomSheetDelegate = self
            listVC.Businesses = self.Businesses
            listVC.parentView = businessListView
            listVC.viewDidLoad()
         }
    }
```

and this the `viewDidLoad()` statement in VC2

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        BusinessListTableView.dataSource = self
        BusinessListTableView.delegate = self 
        BusinessListTableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "BusinessTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "BizCell")
    }
```

I am hoping that someone can help figure out how to get this nib to populate properly. It was working when VC2 is navigated to via a segue.

Comment: It is strange for me, but after all, have you updated your UITableView with .reloadData()?

Comment: How did you setup the view controller containment? You need to add `VC2` as a `child` to the container, add `VC2`'s view to the container's view hierarchy, set `VC2`'s `frame` in the container (set constraints) and then call `didMove(toParent:)`.  See [Apple's Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

Comment: First note: **never** call `viewDidLoad()` - that's called automatically, and if you think it needs to be called, you're doing something else wrong. Next: You say you're *"trying to load a viewcontroller (Lets call this VC2) that contains a tableview into a containerview within a parent viewcontroller (VC1)"* ... show the code you are using to do that. That's likely where you're not doing what you need to do.

Comment: @DonMag I’m embedding VC2 in a container view and that is all done through the interface builder. So there is no code established for that

Comment: Really tough to say with only the information you've provided... *"when I try register the nib or set delegate/data source of the tableview in VC2 I am getting a nil error"* What is nil? You also say *"It was working when VC2 is navigated to via a segue"* .. but the code you've shown ***is*** navigating to it via a segue. Use the debugger to step through your code and inspect the variables so you can figure out what's different between when it's "working" and when it's not.

Comment: I see my issue now. I guess my question now becomes how to asynchronously call the container view. There is data I need that gets retrieved in VC1 that needs to be passed to VC2 simultaneously. Similar to Google maps and the bottom sheet it has.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have a closure when your code retrieves the data? If so, save a reference to "VC2" in `prepareForSegue` and set the data in that closure.

Pseudo code:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    var vc2: ViewController2!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        callToGetData() {
             onCompletion {
                 vc2.Businesses = self.Businesses
                 vc2.reload()
             }
        }

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let listVC = segue.destination as? BusinessListViewController {
            listVC.bottomSheetDelegate = self
            listVC.parentView = businessListView
            vc2 = listVC
         }
    }
}
```